# Befunge-93 interpreter in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, interpreter, befunge

I was doing some [CodeFights](http://codefights.com) and had alot of fun with [this](https://codefights.com/arcade/code-arcade/secret-archives/W59RqZTbGo2vwNSsc/description) [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) challange

## Problem statement

> While exploring the ruins of a golden lost city, you discovered an
>   ancient manuscript containing series of strange symbols. Thanks to
>   your profound knowledge of dead languages, you realized that the text
>   was written in one of the dialects of Befunge-93. Looks like the
>   prophecy was true: you are the one who can find the answer to the
>   Ultimate Question of Life! Of course you brought your futuristic
>   laptop with you, so now you just need a function that will run the
>   encrypted message and make you the all-knowing human being.
>
> [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)-93 is a stack-based programming language, the programs for
>   which are arranged in a two-dimensional torus grid. The program
>   execution sequence starts at the top left corner and proceeds to the
>   right until the first direction instruction is met (which can appear
>   in the very first cell). The torus adjective means that the program
>   never leaves the grid: when it encounters a border, it simply goes to
>   the next command at the opposite side of the grid.
>
> You need to write a function that will be able to execute the given
>   `Befunge-93 program`. Unfortunately your laptop, futuristic that it is,
>   can't handle more than `10^5` instructions and will probably catch on
>   fire if you try to execute more, so the function should exit after `10^5`
>   commands. The good news is, the prophesy said that the answer to the
>   Ultimate Question of Life contains no more than `100` symbols, so the
>   function should return the program output once it contains `100`
>   symbols.
>
> The dialect of Befunge-93 in the manuscript consists of the following
>   commands:
>
> 1. direction instructions:
>
>    - `>`: start moving right
>    - `<`: start moving left
>    - `v`: start moving down
>    - `^`: start moving up
>    - `#`: bridge; skip next cell
> 2. conditional instructions:
>
>    - `_`: pop a value; move right `if value = 0`, left otherwise
>    - `|`: pop a value; move down `if value = 0`, up otherwise
> 3. math operators:
>
>    - `+`: addition; pop `a`, pop `b`, then push `a + b`
>    - `-`: subtraction; pop `a`, pop `b`, then push `b - a`
>    - `*`: multiplication; pop `a`, pop `b`, then push `a * b`
>    - `/`: integer division; pop `a`, pop `b`, then push `b / a`
>    - `%`: modulo operation; pop `a`, pop `b`, then push `b % a`
> 4. logical operators:
>
>    - `!`: logical NOT; pop a value, `if the value = 0`, push 1, otherwise push `0`
>    - `` ` ``: greater than; pop a and b, then push 1 `if b > a`, otherwise `0`
> 5. stack instructions:
>
>    - `:`: duplicate value on top of the stack
>    - `\`: swap the top stack value with the second to the top
>    - `$`: pop value from the stack and discard it
> 6. output instructions:
>
>    - `.`: pop value and output it as an integer followed by a space
>    - `,`: pop value and output it as ASCII character digits
> 7. Other instructions:
>
>    - `0-9`: push the encountered number on the stack
>    - `"`: start string mode; push each character's ASCII value all the way up to the next "
>    - : (whitespace character): empty instruction; does nothing
>    - `@`: end program; the program output should be returned then
>    - `?`: start moving in a random cardinal direction
>
> *If the stack is empty and it is necessary to pop a value, no exception is raised; instead, 0 is produced.*

---

## My code

```
import random
def befunge93(program):
    height = len(program)
    weigth = len(program[0])

    prog_count = 0
    output = ''
    stack = []
    current = program[0][0]

    strmode = False
    location = [0, 0]
    direction = (0, 1)
    step = ()

    def safepop():
        if stack:
            return stack.pop()
        return 0

    while prog_count < 100000 and len(output) < 100:
        if strmode:
            if current == '"':
                strmode = False
            else:
                stack.append(ord(current))
        else:
            if current == '>':
                direction = (0, 1)
            elif current == '<':
                direction = (0, -1)
            elif current == 'v':
                direction = (1, 0)
            elif current == '^':
                direction = (-1, 0)
            elif current == '#':
                step = (direction[0] * 2, direction[1] * 2)
            elif current == '_':
                direction = (0, 1) if safepop() == 0 else (0, -1)
            elif current == '|':
                direction = (1, 0) if safepop() == 0 else (-1, 0)
            elif current == '+':
                stack.append(safepop() + safepop())
            elif current == '-':
                a, b = safepop(), safepop()
                stack.append(b - a)
            elif current == '*':
                stack.append(safepop() * safepop())
            elif current == '/':
                a, b = safepop(), safepop()
                stack.append(b // a)
            elif current == '%':
                a, b = safepop(), safepop()
                stack.append(b % a)
            elif current == '!':
                stack.append(int(safepop() == 0))
            elif current == '`':
                stack.append(int(safepop() < safepop()))
            elif current == ':':
                stack += [safepop()] * 2
            elif current == '\\':
                stack += [safepop(), safepop()]
            elif current == '$':
                safepop()
            elif current == '.':
                output += str(safepop()) + ' '
            elif current == ',':
                a = safepop()
                output += chr(a)
            elif current.isdigit():
                stack.append(int(current))
            elif current == '"':
                strmode = True
            elif current == '?':
                direction = random.choice([(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)])
            elif current == '@':
                break

        if step:
            location[0] += step[0]
            location[1] += step[1]
            step = ()
        else:
            location[0] += direction[0]
            location[1] += direction[1]

        location = [(height + location[0]) % height, (weigth + location[1]) % weigth]
        current = program[location[0]][location[1]]
        prog_count += 1

    return output
```

---

## Note

**Missing standard befunge-93 operations are:**

(Added for completeness sake but not needed for tests)

- `p`: a `put` call. Pop `a`, `b`, and `v`, then change the character at (x,y) in the program to the character with `ASCII value v`
- `g`: a `get` call. Pop `a` and `b`, then push ASCII value of the character at that position in the program
- `&`: ask user for a number and push it
- `~`: ask user for a character and push its ASCII value

---

## Tests

[This link](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge) does not contain correct test data (**[codefights](https://codefights.com/arcade/code-arcade/secret-archives/W59RqZTbGo2vwNSsc/description) and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) does**), if need be I'll add a few more examples.

```
print(befunge93(["               v", 
"v  ,,,,,\"Hello\"<", 
">48*,          v", 
"\"!dlroW\",,,,,,v>", 
"25*,@         > "]))
# >>> Hello world\n
```

**Any** review would be welcome. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some improvement you can do

- gather the four directions `>`,`<`,`^`,`v`
- gather the operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `` ` ``

here are my sample code

```
directions = {
    '>':(0,1),
    '<':(0,-1),
    'v':(1,0),
    '^':(-1,0)
}

operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '`']
def ops(a,b,op):
    if op == '+':
        return a + b
    elif op == '-':
        return b - a
    elif op == '*':
        return a * b
    elif op == '/':
        return b // a
    elif op == '%':
        return b % a
    elif op == '`':
        return int(a<b)
...

#in the while loop, replace the original code
if current in directions:
        direction = directions[current]
elif current in operations:
        stack.append(ops(safepop(), safepop(), current))
```

Comment: why do you do ops this way, rather than 
`operations = {'+' : lambda a,b: a+b,
                          '-' : lambda a,b: a-b,}` and writing
`if current in operations:
    stack.append(operations[current](safepop(), safepop())`

Comment: @Oscar Smith I like `lambda` and this is a good use for it.

Comment: @OscarSmith better than `lambda`, you can make use of the `operator` module. So `operations = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.floordiv}`