# FizzBuzz in Befunge93

Tags: fizzbuzz, befunge

## The intro

Yesterday I learned of the existence of Befunge. See my (sort of) related question about a Befunge [interpreter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177041/befunge-93-interpreter-in-python) in Python. And it made me want to learn the language, and what do programmers do when they learn a new language? They make a `FizzBuzz` of course!

The following program prints all `FizzBuzz's` from `1` until `100`. I don't think this implementation is the best, since I repeat quite a lot of code and there are many empty fields in my program.

You can check it with an online interpreter:

[befunge_online_1](https://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-playground#prog=primes,mode=edit) or [befunge_online_2](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html)

## The explanation

1. Read `"!zzuBzziF"` to stack
2. `>:#,_` While loop to print stack untill stack is empty
3. Go down at the end of the line with `v`
4. Then it prints a newline `,*52,*84<`
5. `+1` Add `1` to top of the stack
6. `:` copy top of stack (current fizzbuz number)
7. `*5*2*25` push `100` to stack
8. go down `v` and go right `>`
9. `` `| `` Checks if current fizzbuz number is bigger than `100`

   - if bigger `@` **end program**
   - if not bigger go down
10. `>:3%` copy stack and modulus with `3`
11. Check modulo `|`

    - `if modulo 3 == 0` print `Fizz` `>"zziF",,,,` and add `1` on top of the stack
    - `if not modulo 3 == 0` add `0` to top of the stack
12. go down `v` and swap top of stack `\` so top op stack is current fizzbuzz number again
13. `%5:<` copy stack and modulus with `5`
14. Check modulo `|`

    - `if modulo 5 == 0` print `Buzz` `,,,,"Buzz"<` swap stack `\` and add `1` on top of it
    - `if not modulo 5 == 0` swap stack `\` and add `0` on top of it
15. go down `v` and go right `>`
16. Check if there was a `Buzz` with `|`

    - if there was a `Buzz` burn top of the stack with `$` **go to step 18**
    - if there was no `Buzz` go down
17. Check if there was a `Fizz` with `|`

    - if there was a `Fizz` do nothing
    - if there was no `Fizz` copy and print the current number `:.`
18. go up and `^` and skip following with `#`
19. go right `>` and go up `^` and **go to step 4**

## The code

```
"!zzuBzziF">:#,_   v
v*2*5*52:+1,*52,*84<
  >@             > ^
>`|   >            v
  >:3%|            0
      >"zziF",,,, 1v
 v\            <   \
 0             |%5:<
 v1\ ,,,,"Buzz"< #  
   >$            ^  
 > |>            ^  
   >|               
    >:.          ^
```

## The output

```
FizzBuzz!
1  
2  
Fizz
4  
Buzz
Fizz 
7  
8  
Fizz 
Buzz
11  
Fizz 
13  
14  
FizzBuzz
...
98
Fizz
Buzz
```

## The question

As stated above, I really don't think my implementation is the best, and am curious how other people would solve this problem.

**My current doubts about the code:**

1. I repeat code, for example prints. **Can they be reworked into functions?**
2. It feels quite large. **Can this be condensed?**
3. Readability of the code. **Do other people understand the steps I've taken?**

I therefore invite you all to **burn** it down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's mine, done basically without consulting yours.

```
v    >          0v    >              v >\#v_:.v
0>:3%|           >\:5%|              >:|  >   v
>    >"zziF",,,,1^    >"zzuB",,,,\1+\^ >\"!",$v
 ^+1 _@#-**455: ,*25                          <
```

My strategy for writing it was just to write the very simplest code possible — the body of the main loop is just

```
if (i divisible by 3) "Fizz"
if (i divisible by 5) "Buzz"
if (i equals 0) "!"
```

and then throw a loop around that. So I started by writing just

```
     >          v   >          v >    v
0>:3%|          >:5%|          >:|    v
>    >"zziF",,,,^   >"zzuB",,,,^ >"!",v
 ^+1 _@#-**455:                       <
```

But this is missing three pieces: (1) there should be a newline after each line; (2) there should be a `:.` to print `i` whenever we don't print `Fizz` or `Buzz`; and (3) we need to *avoid* printing `i` whenever we *did* print `Fizz` or `Buzz`.

(1) is easy to fix; we just add `,*25` to the "carriage return" code along the bottom of the loop.

(3) is awkward. I made an abortive attempt to squeeze a recomputation of something like `::3%!\5%!+#v_:.` (read left-to-right) into the "carriage return" line before realizing that computing logical AND ("i mod 3 AND i mod 5") is awkward in Befunge, *and* I would have to add a fifth line if I wanted to branch again here with `#v_`. So it makes sense to do what you did and keep track of whether we've printed `"Fizz"` or `"Buzz"` as we print them. This lengthens the loop body by a few characters (most of which are `\`).

With (3) out of the way, (2) is easy to squeeze into the blank rectangle in the upper right. As a bonus, if we just printed `"!",` then we know we don't need to test for `:.`!

---

As for your code: It's definitely more convoluted than mine! :D  But in Befunge, this is not necessarily a bad thing.

There are some infelicities; for example you use `*2*5*52:+1,*52,*84` where I would have used `**455:+1,*52` — I don't understand why you bother printing that space character with `*84` since it comes at the end of a line. Possibly a vestige of an earlier version of the code?

On the right-hand side you have a `#` jumping over a `5`. If you were *trying* to be obfuscated, then you could replace this with a codepath that just runs straight through the `5` and then corrects with a `$` further up. You have plenty of white space where a `$` could fit in.

Rather than always using

```
 >A
>|
 >B
```

consider using

```
  >A
>#^_B
```

where it saves you a line. In my long-rusted experience, Befunge idiom still values "small number of lines" over "small number of columns" — the language may be 2D but it's still written by line-oriented chauvinists. :)

---

**Can they be reworked into functions?** — No. :) Befunge-93 has no concept of the (non-`#`) `GOTO`, and as a corollary it has no `GOSUB` and no `RETURN`. I can imagine a programming idiom that applies a binary search tree of "line numbers" down the left side of the program and can "GOTO" a line whose number is specified on the stack; but this would be way overengineered for FizzBuzz.

**Can this be condensed?** — Yes. :)

**Do other people understand the steps I've taken?** — Yes. It's pretty straightforward. :)